# JavaScript: when does addEventListener get executed?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following code:

```
const $details = document.querySelector('.my-details')

const onDetailsToggle = () => {
  console.log('details toggled!')
}

const foo = () => {
  $details.open = true
  $details.addEventListener('toggle', onDetailsToggle, { once: true })
}
foo()
```

I'm baffled - why is `onDetailsToggle` being executed even though the toggle happens *before* I attach the listener?

Comment: It's because of the event loop. Your changes to the DOM are "queued", until the current loop finishes and the browser can update/repaint the UI. That means, your listener is attached, and *then* the browser goes in and updates the UI after the loop is complete, which fires the listener.

Comment: oh duh, thanks @vr., if you answer I'll accept

Comment: [this](https://www.macarthur.me/posts/when-dom-updates-appear-to-be-asynchronous) article says DOM updates are _synchronous_... does the `toggle` listener get triggered when the DOM attribute is updated, or when the paint of the toggled details element happens?

Comment: Did you read further down in the same article? It describes why it happens and what you can do about it. The introduction says it **looks synchronous**, while the rest of the article details why **it isn't**, and **what you can do about it**.

Comment: "The fact that console.log() yields this result isn’t surprising because a DOM update is a synchronous event."  yea - so is it the case that the toggle event is fired when the repaint happens? as opposed to when the attribute is toggled on the dom node?

Comment: Events are fired when the UI changes. Imagine that events did not do this and instead they fired before UI changes. In the *extreme* case, you will have code that executes before the UI is even updated, which may cause some problems (and potentially confuse users of your website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), which is a runtime model that is responsible for executing code, processing events, and executing queued [macro/microtasks](https://javascript.info/event-loop#macrotasks-and-microtasks).

Your first line here doesn't change anything in the UI immediately:

```
$details.open = true;
```

Instead, it queues a task to update the details element. Sure, the underlying HTMLDetailsElement object has changed, but the UI has not. After you do this, you add an event listener, which is added immediately.

```js
$details.addEventListener('toggle', onDetailsToggle, { once: true });
```

The browser has now finished executing the code, so it goes to its task queue (see the 2nd link for more details). It sees that it has to update the UI for the details element, and so it does; but this fires an event that your listener now catches.

To get around it, you can queue the attachment of your event listener as a macrotask:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    $details.addEventListener('toggle', onDetailsToggle, { once: true });
});
```

Comment: I'm open to any corrections as this is getting into some deep waters for me :)